# Center UIView without overlapping neighbors views of different size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

What I wish to achieve, the three of them are UILabels:

[image]

**Spec:**

1. `left` and `right` are edged UIViews.
2. `middle` is centered, even though side views are not the same size.
3. On collision between `middle` and `left` or `middle` and `right`, the text in `middle` gets tail truncated while `left` and `right` do not change.

**Problem:**

I cannot have meet both requirements (2) and (3) at the same time.

- (2) is achieved with `middle.autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis(.Vertical)`

  - problem: no truncate, it just overlaps `leftLabel` and `rightLabel`.
- (3) is achieved with `middle.autoPinEdge(.Left, toEdge: .Right, ofView: leftLabel)` and same strategy for the `rightLabel`.

  - problem: `middle` is centered in the area between `leftLabel` and `rightLabel`, if the last two do not have the same size, `middle` is not superview centered anymore.

Both applied create a constraint conflict and I don't know how to fix it, hence my question:

How can I center a UILabel and truncate it to avoir overlaps with side views of different sizes?

Comment: did i get you right? are all of your three `UILabel`s embedded in `UIView`s?

Comment: If left overlaps middle 10px, do you want middle to be 10px less on its left only or both on its left and right (20px total)?

Comment: @Code only 10px less on the left.

Comment: @AndréSlotta Yes, that's correct.

Comment: How are the labels positioned in the views? Centered?

Comment: @Code `left` and `right` are both `autoPinEdge`d to their respective superview side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is adding two constraints, one is horizontal spacing between middle and left, set the relation to 'Greater than or Equal', and constant for example 10; another is horizontal spacing between middle and right, the same configuration like constraint one.
When the text of middle label is too long, the constraints below will prevent middle from overlapping with label left and right.

**Add sample code:**

I suppose you had set the constraints to `UILabel` left and right in storyboard or in code. The sample below is used to configu `UILabel` middle

```
func setupConstraint() {
    self.middle = UILabel()
    self.middle!.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.view.addSubview(self.middle!)
    self.middle!.numberOfLines = 0
    self.middle!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let middle = self.middle!
    var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: middle, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: left, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: middle, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: left, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)

    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: right, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: middle, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    constraint.priority = 1000

    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: middle, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)

    constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: middle, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: middle, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

    self.view.addConstraint(constraint)

    self.middle!.text = "self.middle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false"
}
```

**Sanpshot**

[image]

Comment: Would you mind show how that would reflect in the code? I am not sure I know how to write these as I only start coding swift recently.

Comment: @oldergod you want to do this with code instead of in storyboard? I will try to write some sample. It maybe take some time as I'm a Objective-C programer

Answer (score 1):

i tried to set up a solution in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let viewController = UIViewController()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = viewController.view

viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let leftView = UIView()
leftView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
leftView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
let leftLabel = UILabel()
leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
leftLabel.text = "leftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleft"
leftView.addSubview(leftLabel)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-2-[leftLabel]-2-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["leftLabel": leftLabel]))
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-2-[leftLabel]-2-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["leftLabel": leftLabel]))

let middleView = UIView()
middleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
middleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
let middleLabel = UILabel()
middleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
middleLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow, forAxis: .Horizontal)
middleLabel.text = "middle"
middleView.addSubview(middleLabel)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-2-[middleLabel]-2-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["middleLabel": middleLabel]))
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-2-[middleLabel]-2-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["middleLabel": middleLabel]))

let rightView = UIView()
rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rightView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
let rightLabel = UILabel()
rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rightLabel.text = "right"
rightView.addSubview(rightLabel)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-2-[rightLabel]-2-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["rightLabel": rightLabel]))
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-2-[rightLabel]-2-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["rightLabel": rightLabel]))

viewController.view.addSubview(leftView)
viewController.view.addSubview(middleView)
viewController.view.addSubview(rightView)

NSLayoutConstraint(item: middleView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewController.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[leftView]->=8-[middleView]->=8-[rightView]|", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: ["leftView": leftView, "middleView": middleView, "rightView": rightView]))
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[leftView]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["leftView": leftView]))
```

results in something like this:

[image: result]

**UPDATE (without embedding the labels in their own views):**

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let viewController = UIViewController()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = viewController.view

viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

let leftLabel = UILabel()
leftLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
leftLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
leftLabel.text = "leftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleftleft"

let middleLabel = UILabel()
middleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
middleLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow, forAxis: .Horizontal)
middleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
middleLabel.text = "middle"

let rightLabel = UILabel()
rightLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rightLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
rightLabel.text = "right"

viewController.view.addSubview(leftLabel)
viewController.view.addSubview(middleLabel)
viewController.view.addSubview(rightLabel)

NSLayoutConstraint(item: middleLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: viewController.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[leftLabel]->=8-[middleLabel]->=8-[rightLabel]|", options: [.AlignAllTop, .AlignAllBottom], metrics: nil, views: ["leftLabel": leftLabel, "middleLabel": middleLabel, "rightLabel": rightLabel]))
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[leftLabel]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["leftLabel": leftLabel]))
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, what is necessary to add all UILabel into its own UIView ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean? every label is in its own view in my answer...

Comment: Why not just add directly `leftLabel`, `middleLabel` and `leftLabel` to `viewController.view`? Did you need to encapsulate every `xxxxLabel` to its own `xxxxView`? UILabel extends UIView so I do not understand the reason here.

Comment: ah. now i understand what you mean. thats also possible of course... i'll update my answer in a second...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The visual format was not really usable for my project, so I chose J.Hunter solution.